# Meta-Analysis - Effect size calculation

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I want to calculate effect sizes for running a meta-analysis.
I am interessted in the difference between two groups after a treatement.
In the papers included for the meta-analysis I often find the mean and standard deviation for each group, as well as (for example) t-values.
In this case, the estimated effect size for the study varies - depending if I use the means and standard deviations for calculation of the t-test.

Which one would be the appropriate estimate - the one calculated based on means or the one calculated based on the t-value?

KR

Comment: Can you edit to give us some more detail? At the moment it is not clear what calculations you are doing to derive the standardised mean difference via either route.

Comment: Sure (and thanks for responding).

Comment: I would like to calculate Hedge g from the mean, standard deviation and group size. I use the package esc in R to calculate effect sizes.

Comment: Its just that I have sometimes the mean, standard deviation and group size and additionally the authors also report the t-values. It is possible to calculate Hedge g via mean, standard deviation and group size as well as thorugh the reported t-value. So I was wondering which values to choose for effect size calculation.

Comment: They should give the same value although if they are not reported with many decimal places they may differ due to rounding error.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Sample size, mean, and standard deviation should be prioritized over other statistics (e.g., t-test or ANOVA values) to estimate standardized mean differences (e.g., Hedges' g).